# Unable to create Android Virtual Devices

Tags: android, ionic2, android-virtual-device

I'm developing a hybrid app using **`ionic2`**.
I have installed android SDK, JDK, ant and necessary things but I'm not able to create avd.

I ran this command- `android avd`
i see the window to create virtual devices. But even after setting every value, I'm not able to click OK.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: "_CPU/ABI: No system images installed for this target_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As

> No system images installed for this target.

indicates you need to open the Android SDK Manager and install the SDK Platform / System image for the Android version you are targeting.

Comment: Okay. Let me try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install these two from sdk.
[image: Like below image]

Answer (score 1):

For creating an Android emulator you must have the system image installed. You can do it either from sdk manager or during the installation.
for doing from sdk manager:

1. open sdkmanager (from android studio `File->settings->Appearence and behaviour -> System settings -> Android Sdk)`
2. Check `more packages` checkbox
3. Click on your desired Android version
4. Check the checkboxes of the system images you want
5. Click appy

For downloading during installation

1. open the `AVD Manager`
2. Create Virtual Device
3. choose the device and press next
4. download the system image